# ASP.NET MVC add another record to a table when creating a new user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

When adding a new user i want to add a record to another table when the user belongs to a specific Role.
where can i add this? where is the logic of the register button?
Thank you :)
[image]

Comment: What have you done so far? It is necessary to provide your codes

Comment: i actually did alot, i'm almost done.
the register button is  built in , and when user is clicking this button and creating a new user i want this user to have another line in payment table.
i cant find the c# code behind the register button unlike all my pages that has a controller to each view

Comment: There must be an endpoint calling when you click Register button! Can you find it? Cause this way it's hard to help without any information about how you register a user, besides how about your tables, what is the relation between tables? Role and User

Comment: Dude, believe me, it's very hard to help with 2 line of explanation and a photo of a web page with a red arrow on it :D

Comment: what code can i provide that will help you? 
it is more of a general question, the user management is built-in in MVC 
so i'm trying to understand it, 
in all my pages there is a view and a controller, 
the register button is built-in with mvc

Answer (score 0):

found it,
registering the user is in file register.cshtml.cs in function OnPostAsync

Comment: Nice answer, A seeker is always a founder :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can write your code in .cs file with the ActionMethod which is specify for the Register button.

If you will share your code how you are value moving from frontend to backend the i can help more with code.

Please share the code block.